# How to interchange assignment of values in Java the most efficient way?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

Say I have the following variables:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
//some calculations follow(x and y stay the same init values) that somehow require you to interchange the values of y and x
```

**how can I set y = 1 and x = 2 in one line of code??**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why that's necessary, but you can do it like:

```
int x = 2, y = 1;
```

Comment: yes but i have to interchange them after the calculations take place

Comment: The question just asked how to assign `x = 2` and `y = 1` on one line. If you want to know how to swap the values stored in `x` and `y`, that's a totally different question. In that case, you'd want to do `int z = x, x = y, y = z;`

Comment: yes good answer.. but I was hoping for a way in which you don't have to store in memory extra variables.

Comment: x = x + y;
y = x - y;
x = x - y;

h/t https://www.w3resource.com/java-exercises/basic/java-basic-exercise-15.php

Comment: That seems like a great way to overflow your variables.

Comment: @holtc seems like an efficient way unless less calculations are possible

Answer (score 0):

Try using bitwise XOR(^) operator.

```
x = x ^ y ^ (y = x);
```

Your completed code may look like,

```
    class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int x = 1, y = 2;
        x = x ^ y ^ (y = x);
        System.out.println("x after swapping:\nx="+x+"\ny after swapping,\ny="+y);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can you explain the line:   x = x ^ y ^ (y = x);

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07VQR78Kzm0  Here is a video to help you.

Comment: yes but when you run your code x = 1 and y = 2 .. i need y = 1 and x = 2

Comment: Assuming that you have print statement after x = x ^ y ^ (y = x)

Comment: I see that it does interchange the values!

Comment: To keep it simple, i will tell you that my code just performs basic xor operation. If you want detailed explanation, watch the video which I have attached in my previous comment.

Comment: I dont understand why is changing them!   I read that XOR returns either 1 or zero

Comment: Conversion of decimal to binary and binary to decimal takes place.

Comment: Binary of 2 is 0010,  so 0s and 1s help to swap the decimal numbers

Comment: yes i see that they turn them into binary and them swap them. its an unusual way with many operations. I was hoping to get the least amount of operations possible

Comment: x = x + y - (y = x);     Try this instead of that xor opration statement

Comment: I never see that you can do such a statement in Java   (y = x) but good way of simplifying

Comment: May I know your purpose of swapping in a single statement?

Comment: I am drawing a rectangle and in order to prevent the left coordinate being greater than the right coordinate I just swap them! so I can avoid drawing problems

Comment: You can use temporary varibles. If you really need to do in a single statement my code will do that.  Why have you restricted yourself to code it in a single statement ?

Comment: cause I'm just really tired of writing so much code. I should change to Kotlin for Android programming. I have been working on a project for 3+ years with probably over 15,000 lines of code. I was a self taught programmer in a way. I have abused the DRY principle in programming. DO NOT REPEAT yourself. I've learned valuable lessons with the project I'm working on.

Comment: Okay, I shared whatever I know. I will keep following this question to read some more answers